# Different path to a file

Tags: node.js

In the main folder of my application, I have another one called `files`. I want to write there some files regardless of where my app is running (locally or from the `dist` folder on a server).

I can prepare some config dependent on environment:
`const path = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? '../files/' : '/files/'` 
but maybe there is another way to do it?

Comment: Maybe [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) is helpful.

Comment: Does it have to run from dist folder? I mean i usually deploy to server only content of dist folder. I never had an issue with different path on server or local.

Comment: @Molda I have an auto-deploy on my server, build by myself. When I push to `git` some update, then on my server new code is pulled, `npm run build` called, an app is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use __dirname (global) to join a different path and store them into different variables. And use them as you need. Check following code

```
    const viewPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/templates/views')
    const partialPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/templates/partials')
    const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/public')
    const path = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? publicPath  : partialPath
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved either by **__dirname** or **process.cwd()**, here is the working piece:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {join} = require('path');

const path = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    ? join(__dirname, './main/files') // ./ means where I am right now; has main directory
    : join(__dirname, './other/files'); // that has 2 more directories files_*

/*const path = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    ? join(process.cwd(), './main/files')
    : join(process.cwd(), './other/files');*/

const randomFileName = `${path}${Date.now()}.txt`;
fs.writeFileSync(randomFileName, 'Write to main/files', 'utf-8');
```

For complete running example clone [file_path_cheat](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/commit/c0db4b5e7d02e2cfca31bbf55f6e889ed6b408d2#diff-49a37d7e94a01b03fc5ef094d5b57498) and run node file_path.